# Analytic proof: $\frac{2}{t^2}-\frac{\frac{1}{2}\cos(\frac{t}{2})}{\sin^2(\frac{t}{2})} \geq 0$ for $t \in [0,\pi]$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, functional-inequalities

I have a relatively simple question:

> How can one show that $\frac{2}{t^2}-\frac{\frac{1}{2}\cos(\frac{t}{2})}{\sin^2(\frac{t}{2})} \geq 0$ $\forall t \in [0,\pi]$ or equivalently why $\frac{1}{\sin(\frac{t}{2})}-\frac{2}{t}$ (with value $0$ at $0$) is an increasing function on $[0,\pi]$ (the former being the derivative of the latter)?

This question came up while showing that the the (absolute value) integral of any subinterval in $[-\pi,\pi]$ of the Dirichlet kernel is bounded by an independent constant (later shown to be e.g. $\frac{\pi}{2}+8$). My attempts included pretty much every known inequality of the type $f(\frac{t}{2}) \leq \sin(\frac{t}{2})$ to bound the function from below and obtain an expression $\geq 0$ after some simplification, but it always seems to be just a tiny bit too coarse.

Thank you for reading and have a good day!

Comment: It appears we have the optimal bound $$\frac{1}{t^2}-\frac{\cos t}{\sin^2t} \geq \frac16$$ over $t\in(0,\pi)$

Comment: @TheSimpliFire The bound you provided (and which can trivially be spotted with any good graphing calculator) suggests that one can probably use Taylor series and the like in a contrived way, but I am not seeing it at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To consider the increasing property of: $$\csc(t/2)-2t^{-1}$$On $[0,\pi]$ Is equivalent to consider the increasing property of $\csc(t)-t^{-1}$ on $[0,\pi/2]$. However, we know that: $$\sin t=t-\frac{1}{6}t^3+O(t^5)$$So that: $$\csc t=\frac{1}{t-\frac{1}{6}t^3+O(t^5)}=t^{-1}+\frac{1}{6}t+\frac{7}{360}t^3+O(t^5)$$From some polynomial division, leaving us with $$\csc t-t^{-1}=\frac{1}{6}t+\frac{7}{360}t^3+O(t^5)$$And the terms wrapped up in $O(t^5)$ are all positive. So, the function is clearly increasing!

See [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Power_Series_Expansion_for_Cosecant_Function) for more.

Comment: How did I not think of using the Taylor expansion of $\csc(t)$! Now it seems bloody obvious, thank you.

Comment: This doesn't really address the heart of the question, since all of the crucial parts lie in "And the terms wrapped up in $O(t^5)$ are all positive". There are ways to show that claim, e.g. by following the rabbit hole down your link, but it's not as simple as being 'bloody obvious'.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u = t/2$. It suffices to prove that, for all $u \in [0, \pi/2]$,
$$-u^2 \cos u + \sin^2 u \ge 0$$
or
$$-u^2\cos u + 1 - \cos^2 u \ge 0$$
or
$$u^4 + 4 \ge (2 \cos u + u^2)^2$$
or
$$\sqrt{u^4 + 4} - u^2 \ge 2\cos u.$$

It is easy to prove that, for all $u\in [0, \pi/2]$,
$$1 - \frac{1}{2}u^2 + \frac{1}{24}u^4 \ge \cos u.$$
(*Note*: Use derivatives. LHS is the 4-th degree Taylor approximation of $\cos u$ around $u = 0$.)

Thus, it suffices to prove that
$$\sqrt{u^4 + 4} - u^2
\ge 2\left(1 - \frac{1}{2}u^2 + \frac{1}{24}u^4\right)$$
or
$$\sqrt{u^4 + 4} \ge 2 + \frac{1}{12}u^4$$
or
$$u^4 + 4 \ge \left(2 + \frac{1}{12}u^4\right)^2$$
or
$$96u^4 \ge u^8$$
which is true.

We are done.